# Why does an ets table survive ct:init_per_testcase but not init_per_suite?

Tags: testing, erlang, common-test

I have a common test suite that attempts to create an ets table for use in all suites and all test cases. It looks like so:

```erlang
-module(an_example_SUITE).
-include_lib("common_test/include/ct.hrl").

-compile(export_all).

all() -> [ets_tests].

init_per_suite(Config) ->
    TabId = ets:new(conns, [set]),
    ets:insert(TabId, {foo, 2131}),
    [{table,TabId} | Config].

end_per_suite(Config) ->
    ets:delete(?config(table, Config)).

ets_tests(Config) ->
    TabId = ?config(table, Config),
    [{foo, 2131}] = ets:lookup(TabId, foo).
```

The `ets_tests` function failed with a badarg. Creating/destroying the ets table per testcase, which looks like so:

```erlang
-module(an_example_SUITE).
-include_lib("common_test/include/ct.hrl").

-compile(export_all).

all() -> [ets_tests].

init_per_testcase(Config) ->
    TabId = ets:new(conns, [set]),
    ets:insert(TabId, {foo, 2131}),
    [{table,TabId} | Config].

end_per_testcase(Config) ->
    ets:delete(?config(table, Config)).

ets_tests(Config) ->
    TabId = ?config(table, Config),
    [{foo, 2131}] = ets:lookup(TabId, foo).
```

Running this, I find that it functions beautifully.

I'm confused by this behavior and unable to determine *why* this would happen, form the [docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/common_test.html#Module%3ainit_per_suite-1). Questions:

- Why does this happen?
- How can I have an ets table to share between a per suite and per testcase?

Comment: Fixed the working example (was just a copy of the nonworking one)

Comment: Added a working example to my code, now runs ok for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the answer by Pascal and as discussed in the [User Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/write_test_chapter.html#id63060) only `init_per_testcase` and `end_per_testcase` run in the same process as the testcase.  Since ETS tables are bound to a owner process your only way to have a ETS table persist during a whole suite or group is to give it away or define a heir process.

You can easily spawn a process in your `init_per_suite` or `init_per_group` functions, set it as heir for the ETS table and pass its pid along in the config.

To clean up all you need is to kill this process in your `end_per_suite` or `end_per_group` functions.

```
-module(an_example_SUITE).
-include_lib("common_test/include/ct.hrl").

-compile(export_all).

all() -> [ets_tests].

ets_owner() ->
    receive
        stop -> exit(normal);
        Any -> ets_owner()
    end.

init_per_suite(Config) ->
    Pid = spawn(fun ets_owner/0),
    TabId = ets:new(conns, [set, protected, {heir, Pid, []}]),
    ets:insert(TabId, {foo, 2131}),
    [{table,TabId},{table_owner, Pid} | Config].

end_per_suite(Config) ->
    ?config(table_owner, Config) ! stop.

ets_tests(Config) ->
    TabId = ?config(table, Config),
    [{foo, 2131}] = ets:lookup(TabId, foo).
```

You also need to make sure you can still access your table from the testcase process, by making it either `protected`or `public`

Comment: Indeed they run on the same process.To quote the erlang documentation
" As init_per_testcase and end_per_testcase execute on the same Erlang process as the test case, printouts from these configuration functions are included in the test case log file. "

http://erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/write_test_chapter.html#id63060

Answer (score 2):

An ets table is attached to a process and destroyed as soon as the process ends, unless you use the the give_away function (which is not feasible I fear in this case)

As state in the common tets doc, each test case and the init_per_suite and end_per_suite are run in separate processes, so the ets table is destroyed as soon as you leave the init_per_suite function.

fron common_test doc

> init_per_suite and end_per_suite will execute on dedicated Erlang
>   processes, just like the test cases do. The result of these functions
>   is however not included in the test run statistics of successful,
>   failed and skipped cases.

from ets doc

> The default owner is the process that created the table. Table
>   ownership can be transferred at process termination by using the heir
>   option or explicitly by calling give_away/3.

Comment: Well it is feasible ... see my answer